# add constraint to plugin domain class

Tags: grails

In order to support [UTFMB8 encoding](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) I added the following default constraint in `Config.groovy`

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(maxSize: 191)

    unlimitedSize(maxSize: Integer.MAX_VALUE)
}
```

I also added the `unlimitedSize` shared constraint which I use in some of my domain classes to override this default, e.g.

```
class BlogPost {
    String body

    static constraints = {
        body shared: 'unlimitedSize'
    }
}
```

However, there are a couple of classes in plugins that also need to override the default `maxSize` of 191. In these cases, I can't use the shared constraint, because I can't edit the source code. One option is to copy the classes into my application, and edit the copies (because artifacts in an application override those in plugins), but this is not very appealing because I've then effectively forked those classes.

Is there a better way? For example, is it possible for me to add constraints to these domain classes in `Bootstrap.groovy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constraints can be added during boostrap something like:

```
class BootStrap {
    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { GrailsDomainClass gdc ->
            Class domainClass = gdc.clazz
            if (domainClass.simpleName == 'BookFromPlugin') {

                def field = domainClass.declaredFields.find {
                    it.name == 'body' && it.type == String
                }

                if (field) {
                    domainClass.constraints.body.maxSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `BookFromPlugin` is a domain class from plugin and `body` is a property from the domain class. This can be optimized and made applicable to more than one domain class.

Since bootstrap is the last thing that is taken care of, it should eventually override the constraint previously defined in domain class.

**UPDATE:**
I guess you meant `domainClass.constraints` is accessing the private variable from domain class, but that is not true. `domain.constraints` gives a map where propery name is mapped to all its constraints. This is map is taken from `ConstrainedProperty` which is comprised of 3 elements: class owning the constraint, property name where constraint will be applied and the type of the property.

So when we use `domain.constraints.body` it actually gives a list of constraints applied to `body` as the value for key `body`. Each element in the list is a [`ConstrainedProperty`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/ConstrainedProperty.java#L201).

By calling `setMaxSize()` we are just adding another `ConstrainedProperty` to the list of constraints.

Comment: With a couple of small changes, it works, thanks! However, I think `domainClass.constraints` is accessing a private variable, which is a bit naughty. I wonder if it's possible to achieve the same result without accessing private fields?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and sorry I didn't test it before leaving for home on a late Friday. :) Have a look at my update to answer. Was too long for a comment.

Comment: Also note I had the type of the field checked as `String` from the example to make sure `maxSize` constraint is applied to a String property only. Was that creating any noise while is use? @Don